# How can I write result of mean, min, max, median, P-value and anderson-darling test result on the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had a problem when I made a plot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj32h.png)

I want to add result of mean, min, max, median, P-value and anderson-darling test on the right side of the plot.
But I don't know how post each result like 'mean = 70.0'
please answer me how can I write proper code.

```
library(xlsx)
library(nortest)
library(ggplot2)
data1=read.xlsx("data_example.xlsx",1)
study1=data1$Normal
y=dnorm(study1,mean(study1),sd(study1))
norm= data.frame(study1,y)
min=min(study1)
max=max(study1)
mean=mean(study1)
median=median(study1)
sd=sd(study1)
ggplot(norm, aes(x=study1)) + geom_histogram(aes(x=study1,y=..density..), 
binwidth=2, color='black', fill='blue', alpha='.2') +
labs(title = 'Normal에 대한 요약보고서') + 
geom_density(aes(x=study1,y=..density..)) +
annotate("text", label = min, x = 100, y = .04, color = "black") + 
annotate("text", label = max, x = 100, y = .035, color = "black") +
annotate("text", label = mean, x = 100, y = .03, color = "black") + 
annotate("text", label = median, x = 100, y = .025, color = "black")
```

Comment: Welcome Ian. Please proved reproducible test data. Make you data small, use something like `dput(data1)` and include that in your question.You get more answers that way because it is easier to help. Try something like `label = paste("min =", min)` in your annotate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

Generate a normally distributed data:

```
set.seed(11235813)
x <- rnorm(2000, mean = 70.0, sd = 11.5)
```

Calculate the parameters (`min`, `max`, ... ), and convert the results to the character vector:

```
xpars <- sapply(c("min", "max", "mean", "median", "sd"), do.call, list(x = x)) %>%
  round(., 2) %>%
  paste(names(.), ., sep = " = ") %>%
  paste(., collapse = "\n")
```

Make `x` a `data.frame`, and plot the data (I just slightly modified your code):

```
data.frame(x = x) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 2, 
                     colour = "black", fill = "blue", alpha = .2) +
      geom_density(aes(y = ..density..), colour = "red", lty = 2) +
      annotate(
               "text",  
               x     = .9 * max(x), 
               y     = .9 * max(density(x)$y), 
               label = xpars, 
               hjust = 0
               ) +
      ggtitle("Normal에 대한 요약보고서") +
      theme_classic()
```

[image: histogram_with_summary]